# Error retry strategy and function argument binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, swr

I'd like to make my swr state mutations resilient against network errors and support some kind of retry functionality.

Basically what I do is inside my useSWR powered react hook:

```js
const setFavourite = useCallback((objectId) => {
  const url = `/favs/${objectId}`
  const newData = [objectId, ...data]
  return mutate(newData, false)
    .then(() => request("POST", url))
    .then(() => mutate())
    .catch((error) => {
      mutate(data, false).catch(() => {})
      const userError = new Error("Could not add favourite")
      userError.retry = () => setFavourite(objectId)
    })
}, [data, mutate, request])
```

I generate a new Error object with a `retry` function that can be used by the UI code to show a toast to retry the operation at later time (upon user interaction).

I wonder if the dependencies to setFavourite are still valid at the time `retry()` would be called. I guess not, as they depend on `data` and if this changes, then the `setFavourite` is also regenerated.

Anybody implemented such kind of retry before?